# Start Activity on BOOT_COMPLETED without BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I know that I can start activity on boot by calling it from a BroadcastReceiver but what if I wanted to do the following:

```
<activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

is this possible? and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is this possible?

No.

First, `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is a broadcast `Intent`. You cannot respond to it via an `<activity>` or `<service>` manifest element.

Second, `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` will prevent anything from starting your activity, unless it *also* holds `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`. That is not how you usually use that particular permission.

Comment: Could we start a foreground service on **BOOT_COMPLETED**, and have a Pending Intent from its notification to open the Activity?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: AFAIK, that is fine.